# How to put recycler viewer + button in one layout

Tags: android-studio

I tried many combinations, but how to get my horizontal recyclerviewer at the bottom with a button above, using a constrain layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".FirstFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/btn_add_note"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

   <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="bottom"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:scrollbars="horizontal"
       app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btn_add_note"
       tools:listitem="@layout/recyclerview_note">

   </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**After that, I get a render error, saying.**

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidget.setWrapWidth(I)V   at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1242)   at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure_Original(ConstraintLayout.java:1572)   at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:-1)   at android.view.View.measure_Original(View.java:24552)   at android.view.View_Delegate.measure(View_Delegate.java:80)   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24516)   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)   at android.view.View.measure_Original(View.java:24552)   at android.view.View_Delegate.measure(View_Delegate.java:80)   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24516)   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:735)   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:481)   at android.view.View.measure_Original(View.java:24552)   at android.view.View_Delegate.measure(View_Delegate.java:80)   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24516)   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)   at android.view.View.measure_Original(View.java:24552)   at android.view.View_Delegate.measure(View_Delegate.java:80)   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24516)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_add_note"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Hey, you might know why MainActivity is complaing about context?                                 
```val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.my_recycler_view)
        val adapter = NoteListAdapter(this)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(recyclerView)```

Comment: The recycler view is inside a fragment.